# Notepad++ keyboard shortcut to select the remaining part of document before cursor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Notepad++ to select the whole part of document before cursor?

Assume the text file is:

```
Hi Guys
Hello
How[The cursor is here] are you?
```

Then it will select

```
Hi Guys
Hello
How
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you can hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd>.

- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is used to select text by moving cursor.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> will take cursor to the beginning of the file.

Where <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> will do the opposite thing, select after the cursor.

If you remove <kbd>CTRL</kbd> it will just select in the current lines.